# PlaySpecification not found in Play 2.6.3

Tags: scala, playframework, specs2

I've imported Specs2 and everything looks good but some things that are not imported, among them the PlaySpecification trait.
I've tried to reload in sbt, to invalidate caches in Intellij ...  But this trait is missing!

My built.sbt

```
name := """web2"""
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
scalaVersion := "2.12.2"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala, LauncherJarPlugin)
pipelineStages := Seq(digest)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  evolutions,
  jdbc,
  ehcache,
  ws,
  "com.softwaremill.macwire" %% "macros" % "2.3.0" % "provided",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.1",
  "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc" % "3.0.0",
  "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc-config" % "3.0.0",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3",
  "de.svenkubiak" % "jBCrypt" % "0.4.1",
  //"org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.0.+" % "test",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.7.22" % "test",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.9.+" % "test"
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

plugins.sbt

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.3")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.2")
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTestingWithSpecs2#Using-specs2), replace `"org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.9.+" % "test"` with `specs2 % Test` in your dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  evolutions,
  jdbc,
  ehcache,
  ...
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.7.22" % "test",
  specs2 % Test
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why does it needs to be like that and not like I posted?